# Spotify web API - 401 Permissions missing

Tags: php, spotify

I'm trying to build a spotify web player using the spotify web API.
I registered my Application on spotify and whitelist the callback URL.
Then the authorization process works fine. I receive the token for make others requests.
But when I try to make a simple currently-playing request,

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-the-users-currently-playing-track/

I receive

```
Array ( [error] => Array ( [status] => 401 [message] => Permissions missing ) )
```

the PHP code is:

```
session_start();
$req = $_SESSION['token_type'] . " " . $_SESSION['token'];
$headers_after_token = array(
   "Accept: */*",
   "Authorization: " . $req);
$url="https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing";
echo "<br>REQ-currently-playing: ".$req."<br>";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_after_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<br><br>";
print_r($response);
```

the `$_SESSION['token_type']` contains "Bearer" as mentioned in the API endpoint-reference
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/

the `$_SESSION['token']` contains the token retrieved after the authentication process.

Both are well formed thanks to the `echo "<br>REQ-currently-playing: ".$req."<br>";` I can see that the 2 variables are set.

I'm using XAMPP v3.2.2 for deploy php pages.

Comment: When you authorized the user, did you have the  `user-read-currently-playing`  and/or `user-read-playback-state` scope?

Comment: Did you solve the issue or have you given up?

Comment: no of course I didn't give up, no I don't have this scope. Where I have to insert that string?

Comment: ok it works with `scope` inside the first request. Thanks. So if I need others privileges I need to resend the `authorization` ? 
If you write an answer I can set as "solution". Thanks again

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, I couldn't help it ... I have a friend in Sweden named Erik Magnusson!  How rare is this?  (Sorry, guys!)

Comment: @Apostolos - Both our first and last names are very common :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be able to fetch the current playing, you need to add the scope `user-read-currently-playing` and/or `user-read-playback-state` when you authorize a user.

With this kind of authorization, a user needs to agree what your app can do on their behalf. Some things are included by default, but some things (just like this) needs extra permissions from the user.

If you see in the documentation that it says that a function needs "this and that" scope, you need to add it to the authorization.